# Summary Fields Extension - Do the contribution fields include event/membership payments

Tags: civievent, extension, contributions

For the Summary Fields Extension - Do the contribution fields (i.e "Total Lifetime Contributions") include event/membership payments?

Also, related question, if it does include event payments, does it include partial payments?

A blog about this extension is here:  https://civicrm.org/extensions/summary-fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the contribution types you want to include (there is a setting page). I don't know about partial payments though...

Answer (score 1):

Yes the contribution fields can include event fees/contributions, membership payments, pretty much whatever you like. For Civi 4.6.9, and earlier versions, go to Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Summary Fields and you'll see the Summary Fields Administration settings page. If a partial payment has a Financial Type, it should appear. The admin choices are pretty intuitive.

Comment: Thanks -- for partial payment, I was referring to the partially paid  status for a contribution (i.e Event payment).

Comment: You are welcome, did you find what you need?